# When to use a new cache name?

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

When should I reuse a cache in Ehcache and when should I create a new one?

Example 1:

I have the following methods:

```
public Dog getBestDog(String name) {
    //Find the best dog with the provided name
}

public Dog getBestBrownDog(String name) {
    //Find the best brown dog with the provided name
}
```

For a given String (e.g. "rover"), these two methods could return a different Dog object.

Should I annotate them both with `@Cacheable(cacheName = "dogs")` or should I put them in two different caches, "bestDogs" and "bestBrownDogs"?

Example 2:

I have the following methods:

```
public Dog getBestDogByName(String name) {
    //Find the best dog with the provided name
}

public Dog getBestDogByColour(String colour) {
    //Find the best dog with the provided colour
}
```

Name "rover" and colour "doggy-colour" could return the same Dog.

Should I annotate them both with `@Cacheable(cacheName = "dogs")` or should I put them in two different caches, 'dogsByName' and 'dogsByColour'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a scenario where the same key can result in different results, then you probably want a separate cache.

Example 1:

`getBestDog(name)` - use the name as the key from 'best-dogs' cache

`getBestBrownDog(name)` - use the name as the key from 'best-brown-dogs' cache

Example 2:

`getBestDogByName(name)` - same as example 1, use name as key from 'best-dogs' cache

`getBestDogByColour(colour)` - use colour as key from 'best-dogs-by-colour' cache

Which leaves you with 3 caches, 'best-dogs', 'best-brown-dogs', 'best-dogs-by-colour'

In theory, you could merge 'best-dogs' and 'best-dogs-by-colour'... but maybe you have a dog who is called 'red'.. so that would be an unaccounted for edge case.

Answer (score 3):

Using differing caches can work.  You can also use the same cache, just set them with different keys by using SpEL with something like the following:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "dogs", key = "'name.'+#name")
public Dog getBestDogByName(String name) {
    //Find the best dog with the provided name
}

@Cacheable(cacheName = "dogs", key = "'colour.'+#colour")
public Dog getBestDogByColour(String colour) {
    //Find the best dog with the provided colour
}
```

Comment: Will this do anything clever like storing only one copy of an object if it's returned by both methods with different keys?

Comment: It will not, unless there is a way to configure that within ehcache.